# PHP: How to receive multiple values with ajax?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a page `practice2.html` in which a customer selects the product, color and quantity.  After the user submits, the values are sent along with the product price and balance to another page `addtocart.php` via ajax.

The `addtocart.php` page receives those values, connects to the database and inserts those values.  However, `addtocart.php` is not receiving those values and no values are visible in the alerts messages in the code below.

I think there is a problem in the `addtocart.php` page on line `if(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')` but I do not know how to fix it:

```php
    practice2.php
      function addtocart(price){
      var productdetails=document.forms['mehendicones'].value;
      var pcolor=document.getElementById('mehendi_color').value;
    var pquantity=document.getElementById('quantity_mehendi_color').value;
         var bal=price*pquantity;
             var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
              ajax.open("POST","addtocart.php",true);
                ajax.send(productdetails,pcoloR,price,pquantity,bal);
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
           alert(this.responseText);
                    }
                }
        }

     addtocart.php
         <?php
        include 'includes/database.php';

           // I think there is an issue with the post call here
           if(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){
           $pdetails=file_get_contents("php://input");
            $pcolor=file_get_contents("php://input");
             $price=file_get_contents("php://input");
             $pquantity=file_get_contents("php://input");
              $pbal=file_get_contents("php://input");
            }
            $fname=$_SESSION['firstname'];
           $id=$_SESSION['id'];
            $nam=$_SESSION['code']; 

        $sql="INSERT INTO ".$nam." 
                 (pdetails,price,pquantity,pcolor,bal) VALUES 
               ('$pdetails','$pcolor','$price','$pquantity','pbal');";

        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "added to cart";
        }else{
            echo "couldnot add to cart..try again";
        }
            mysqli_close($con)
                ?>
```

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send), the send() method only accepts one parameter. That parameter must contain all the values in one string. The standard format to put it in is querystring format (i.e. `param1=ABC&param2=def&param3=42`), or if your server code is set up to read it, you could use JSON or XML, or any other format you choose. But the point is you must supply a single string containing all the values in a suitable machine-readable format.

Comment: If you use the querystring format I suggested then in the PHP all the variables will be named items inside the `$_POST` array. Frankly I'm surprised you didn't find tutorials already which show you the proper way to do it. There are thousands of Ajax tutorials out there online. I've never seen anyone try to do it this way before

Comment: @ADyson ok thank you loads....will try what you said

Comment: The most common way that I see this done is that you define a `<form>` somewhere in the HTML file that also contains the AJAX.  This form contains hidden fields.  And then, what you do is to `submit()` that form from the JavaScript code.  If you have a lot of information to submit, you can JSON-encode the data and send that.